# Char and printf printing jibberish

Tags: c, printf

I'm a newbie to C/C++. I'm working through a tutorial and can't figure out what I messed up. I keep getting jibberish as a result. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char code[] = 
"\xb8\x8d\x5d\xfe\x19\xdb\xc9\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x29\xc9\xb1"
"\x1c\x31\x43\x12\x03\x43\x12\x83\x4e\x59\x1c\xec\x8b\xa4\x39"
"\x7b\x0f\xdd\xe5\x3a\xfc\x64\x02\xcb\x33\x5e\x83\xde\x02\x17"
"\xfc\x63\xa3\xd3\xff\x14\x8c\x47\x12\xef\x12\x7c\xf6\xce\x81"
"\xec\xf2\x45\x2a\x76\xa0\xe3\x32\xa2\xf6\xee\x65\x5e\xa4\x7e"
"\xd6\x46\xa4\x1f\x62\xcd\x88\x35\x72\x0e\x6b\x7a\xdf\x08\xc9"
"\xab\x0f\xc6\x5a\xd6\xc9\xc5\xe8\x04\x17\x65\xa3\x47\x76\xac"
"\x6b\xa7\xce\x3d\x82\x18\x03\x20\x2a\x9b\x24\x13\xa1\x5a\x08"
"\x0d\x98\x1e\xa1\x74\xe9\xd4\xc0\xdc\x88\xda\xab\x74\xec\x63";

int main()
{
    //int i;
    //for (i=0;i<sizeof code; i++){
    //  code[i] = code[i] ^0xcc;
printf(code);
    //}

}
```

I commented out those bits because I was trying to figure out where the problem is. Ultimately I want to leave them in and see what result I get. But with them in or out, I get jibberish.

I'm sure I'm using printf wrong, but how do I make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to output? That array doesn't look like ASCII at first glance.

Comment: @Mat prob some 37it3 h4xor shellcode

Comment: @Mat: Wrong, string literals and arrays initialized with a string literal using `[]` are **always** null terminated.

Comment: What do you expect as output? To me gibberish IS the expected result. So I don't see a problem, thought using %s like Ed Heal answered would be safer.

Comment: I've looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ but didn't have luck. The output should look like the original 'code' (in the \xb8\x8d\etc. format, but with different data).

Comment: Funny, I didn't know the Obfuscated C Contest issued a tutorial.

Comment: A good chunk of those codes fall outside the normal ASCII character set (0x00 to 0x7f).  For example, "\xb8" corresponds to a graphical character (sort of looks like a short, backwards F according to the extended ASCII table  at http://www.asciitable.com).  I'd say that particular string isn't meant to be written to the console with `printf`.

Comment: Throw your tutorial away, now. **It** is gibberish.

Comment: @mrlippy: what people are trying to tell you is that you should do: `printf("%s\n", code);`. The result can't be anything else but gibberish, since the input is gibberish. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

Try `printf("%s", code);`

That might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But nope. I still get the same jibberish. It's kind of like Wingdings.

Comment: I was assuming that the array was unicode. Why not put char code[] = "hello world!"

Comment: `printf("%s", code)` is certainly better than `printf(code)`, because the latter interprets code as a format string, but in this case it's going to produce exactly the same output (unless `code` contains one or more `'%'` characters).

Comment: The third character, "\x5d", is equivalent to "]" in ASCII -- do you see that "]" when you run the program (with the "%s")? The original source string doesn't look like ASCII text, so I'm not too surprised you're getting gibberish out. ("garbage in, garbage out"). Which tutorial did this come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<sizeof code - 1; i++){
      code[i] = code[i] ^0xcc;
    }
    puts(code);
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still jibberish. Albeit different jibberish than before.

Answer (score 0):

\xb8 means a char with value 0xB8 hex... \x8d means the char with value 0x8D hex... no one's going to sit around and decode the entire string for you. It looks like printf is working perfectly but garbage in, garbage out :)
Actually you made me curious so here's how it looks in a linux console:
torp@torp:~/work/clocal$ ./gibberish 
��t���܈ګt�c)ɱ1CC�NY실9{��:�d�3^���c����G�|�΁��E*v��2���e^�~�F�b5rkzɫ�Z����e�Gv�k��=�▒ *�$�Z

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the contents of `code` *are* gibberish.  It's not ASCII, UTF-8, Latin-1, or EBCDIC.  When write it to a file and run the `file` command on it, it just says "data".  And when I restore the commented-out code, which xors each byte with `0xcc`, it's still gibberish.

So when your program prints gibberish, it's doing exactly what it should.

What tutorial are you using?  What did it tell you to expect?

Comment: It looks like the exercise is to reverse "xor encryption".

Comment: Yes, but the original data and the xor'ed data are both gibberish.  I'd like to see what the tutorial has to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "%x" or "X" format specifiers:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(code); ++i)
{
    printf("\\x%02x", (unsigned int) code[i]);
    if ((i % 15) == 14)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
printf("\n");
```